# Cannot create class in AHK after destruction

Tags: class, object, autohotkey, construction, destruction

I'm trying to wrap my head around classes in AHK. I'm C++ dev, so would like to make use of RAII (`__New`, `__Delete`), but it looks like I miss some concepts since things look very contra-intuitive for me.

After some tries I came up with this simple example:

```
class Scenario
{
  __New()
  {
    MsgBox, NEW
  }

  __Delete()
  {
    MsgBox, DELETE
  }
}

scenario := new Scenario
scenario := new Scenario
scenario := 1
scenario := {}
scenario := new Scenario
Return
```

As a result I get the following messages:

1. NEW
2. NEW
3. DELETE
4. DELETE

Questions:

1. Why doesn't the object get destroyed during the second assignment? I'd assume the number of refs going to 0, no?
2. How come I get 2 destructions in a row? Where was that object stored meanwhile? How could `scenario` variable hold both references?
3. Why was not the third construction called?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why doesn't the object get destroyed during the second assignment?

Garbage collection had not been triggered yet

> I'd assume the number of refs going to 0, no?

References going to 0 does not necessarily trigger GC

> 2. How come I get 2 destructions in a row?

Garbage collection cleaned both references at the same time

> Where was that object stored meanwhile?

The heap

> How could scenario variable hold both references?

`scenario` does not hold both references

> 3. Why was not the third construction called?

Only two Scenario objects are constructed. The variable `scenario` is a dynamic variable and is not always an instance of the class `Scenario`.  The last assignment `scenario := {}` just creates an empty object.

Comment: Ok, I think I forgot to add one more line in the end - one more `scenario := ...` before return - updated the code. It looks like assigning to `{}` triggers garbage collection and I cannot create a new object after that anymore. This still doesn't answer why it is not collected when ref counter goes to zero. Do you have a link to documentation where the whole garbage collection is described?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out what was missing. Two things:

1. AHK script is case-insensitive.
2. Since `class` is an object by itself in AHK it's possible to override the class by another object.

[Here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Custom_Classes) is a piece of the documentation:

> Because the class is referenced via a variable, the class name cannot be used to both reference the class and create a separate variable (such as to hold an instance of the class) in the same context. For example, `box := new Box` would replace the class object in Box with an instance of itself. [v1.1.27+]: `#Warn ClassOverwrite` enables a warning to be shown at load time for each attempt to overwrite a class.

This explains what happened in the code above: variable name `scenario` is effectively the same as a class name `Scenario`, so I just quietly overrode my class with an empty object.

Also, since the new instance of the class is created before assignment, I got two 'NEW' in a row, only than 'DELETE'.